# Fluent NHibernate: How to change hasMany relationship Foreign Key constrain name instead of FK+Random ID?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
    public Parent()
    {
        Children = new List<Child>();
    }
}
public class Child
{
    public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public ParentMap()
{
        Map(x => x.Number).Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Children)
            .Cascade.None()
            .KeyColumn("ParentId")
            .ExtraLazyLoad()
            .AsSet();
}
```

Sql script generated:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Child]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FKFCFBAA864983AA6A] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Parent] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Child] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FKFCFBAA864983AA6A]
GO
```

How to change the Foreign Key format of `[FKFCFBAA864983AA6A]` to `[FK_ChildTableName_ParentTableName]`?

Comment: `.ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_MyKey")` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Rabban comment, `.ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_MyKey")` is the trick.

For mapping,

```
public ParentMap()
{
        Map(x => x.Number).Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Children)
            .Cascade.None()
            .KeyColumn("ParentId")
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_Children_Parent") //customize Foreign Key name
            .ExtraLazyLoad()
            .AsSet();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done by convention if you are using automapping

```
public class ForeignConstraintNamingConvention : IHasManyConvention, IReferenceConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.OtherSide != null)
        {
            instance.OtherSide.ForeignKey(GetForeignConstraintName(instance.TableName, instance.OtherSide.Columns.First().Name));
        }
    }
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        instance.ForeignKey(GetForeignConstraintName(instance.EntityType.Name, instance.Name));
    }
    
    private static string GetForeignConstraintName(string tableName, string columnName)
    {
        return $"FK_{tableName}_{columnName}";
    }
}
```

Then adding this to your configuration

```
    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(sqlConfiguration)
        .Mappings(m =>
            m.AutoMappings
                .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<AnEntityInYourAssembly>(automappingConfiguration)
                .Conventions.Setup(
                        c =>
                        {
                            c.Add<PrimaryKeyConvention>();
                            c.Add<CustomForeignKeyConvention>();
                            c.Add<StringLengthConvention>();
                            c.Add<ForeignConstraintNamingConvention>();
                        }
                        )))
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, false, false))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```